# Transform string to list of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this string

```
'['foo', 'faa', 'fee']'
```

I want to transform it as a list of strings like:

```
['foo', 'faa', 'fee']
```

how could I do that?

Comment: I would start by fixing whatever is producing that string. Python string representations are meant for debugging and display purposes, not for sharing data between processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ast` package

```
from ast import literal_eval

s = "['foo', 'faa', 'fee']"
l = literal_eval(s)
print(type(l))
```

Output

```
<class 'list'>
```